# How to use IFNA, and create the value if NA as a text string plus sequential numbering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to make the value_if_na portion of the IFNA formula the text string "Vacant" and then a sequential number to ensure no repeating values. If there is any advice on how best to encompass this I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Image of the problem I am looking to complete. The yellow highlighted portion is the ideal end result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(ISNA(A2),"Vacant "&COUNTIF(A:A,"Vacant *")+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,"#N/A")+1,A2)
```

[image]